# Count number of times a number is found between two columns in excel

Tags: excel

I have two columns (A and B) and I want to know how many times a number from column B is found in column A. They do not have to be on the same row, just within the same column.

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVZit.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify if you wanted a formula, or a VBA/Macro solution...

#### Formula Solution (as posted by @dwarduk) With Extended Explanation

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A, $B1)
```

- `COUNTIF(...)` — accepts two arguments, the first is the range to look in, and the second is the value to look for. It returns the number of times the value is found in the range. Note that the second argument does not have to be a reference to a cell.
- `$A:$A` — Means every cell in column **A** (same as `$A$1:$A$65535`)
- `$B1` — Means the first cell in column **B**. Note that because the `1` is not preceeded by a dollar sign (`$`) it will increment or decrement appropriately if you past the formula in another row. So, you would want to make sure you past this formula in **C1** first, then fill the cells below it.

Additional Note: `COUNTIF(...)` operates on the actual value of the cells, it does not operate on the formatted value of the cells. So, if you have `826.2` in a cell in column **A**, but have the Number Formatting set to drop all decimal places, this will not be counted by a value of `826` in column **B**. Even though to the naked eye they appear to be the same.

#### Alternative Formula Option

If your values in column **B** are hard coded. Simply replace the values in column **B** with the `COUNTIF(...)` formula and use the respective number as the second argument. Here is an example of what **B1** would look like.

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A,444)
```

#### VBA/Macro Solution

This will populate the cells in column **C** with the number of times the respective value in column **B** is found in column **A**.

```vb
Public Sub CountA_FillC()

    Dim RowA As Long, RowB As Long
    Dim UsedRange As Range: Set UsedRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For RowB = 1 To UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Dim Count As Long: Count = 0
        For RowA = 1 To UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If UsedRange(RowA, "A").Value = UsedRange(RowB, "B").Value Then
                Count = Count + 1
            End If
        Next RowA
        UsedRange(RowB, "C").Value = Count
    Next RowB

End Sub
```

Comment: The first countif function does not work. It gives me a value of 0 even if the number in column B is in column A! How can I upload a sheet here so I can show you?

Comment: Assuming you have a Google account, you could upload it to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/), make it public, and paste the link here. Microsoft also has Sky Drive, or if you use DropBox, you can upload it to a public folder.

Comment: Something else that would suffice is highlight the cell you've pasted the formula in, take a screenshot and make sure **A1**, the Formula Bar, and the highlighted cell (with the formula in it) are visible in the screenshot.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. here is the file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74357710/StackOverflow1%20(1)EXAMPLE.xls   As you can see, it says 826 is not present in column A, even though it is! Can you help?

Comment: @user28246 Please examine your data more closely. The value in Cell `A29` is not actually `826`, but rather it is `826.2`.  The 'CountIf` function requires an **exact** match.  All data in cell `A19` down contains a trailing decimal.

Answer (score 1):

`=COUNTIF($A:$A,$B1)`, where $B1 actually means $B<row number>

Not really much of an explanation, but it works pretty much like a "count if equal to"

Comment: I tried it in excel 2010 and it works fine for me.  Obviously I can't test on your machine, though.  Here's my file; does this one work for you?  [StackOverflow1.xls](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/867796/StackOverflow1.xls)

Comment: How do I upload an excel file here. I will show you how it is not working... cheers,