# Excel - Count how many rows have equal numbers in two columns

Tags: excel

[image]

As described in my picture, the goal is to count how many times "AAA", "BBB", and "CCC" in column A have column B and C equal to each other in their respective rows. The values in column B and C are whole numbers. I haven't hidden any decimal places.

I realize I could simply add an extra column where I go B1=C1 (B2=C2... and so on), and then running a COUNTIFS formula to count the number of TRUE cells. That's plan B. I feel like there's a way to do this without bloating my worksheet with an extra column of data though...

I referenced the following thread:
[Count number of times a number is found between two columns in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625632/count-number-of-times-a-number-is-found-between-two-columns-in-excel)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A="AAA")*(B:B=C:C))
```

Also I suggets you to use exact ranges to make formula faster:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100="AAA")*(B1:B100=C1:C100))
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you! I did some more playing around, and I realized what your solution was doing was just playing with AND Gate logic. What I don't understand is why SUMPRODUCT is being used the way it is.

Comment: You're absolutelly right! it's boolean logic. `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100="AAA")*(B1:B100=C1:C100))` gives you `=SUMPRODUCT({TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,..}*{FASLE,TRUE,FALSE,..})` where only `TRUE*TRUE` gives you 1 and other combinations - 0. So it's evaluates to `0+1+0+..` and sumproduct sum this values to give you result

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip on using exact ranges. I'd actually realized the need to do this just before posting this. On my real spreadsheet (where there are way more formulas), I edited all my formulas to not use exact ranges on the suggestion of a friend. The result of my workbook was getting a 2 second lag for every cell of data I tried to enter. All I have to say is, I'm glad the spreadsheet was stored on Dropbox. Dropbox's version control allowed me to revert my spreadsheet in a few clicks.

Comment: OK, I think I see why SUMPRODUCT() is used now. It's because it takes arrays as its parameters as opposed to numbers in SUM().

Comment: actually you can also use `=SUM((A1:A100="AAA")*(B1:B100=C1:C100))`, but it requires array entry (i.e. you should press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to evaluate it), while using `SUMPRODUCT` doesn't require array entry (because by design this function is already array function)

Comment: I was just trying to do the same thing in Excel 2016. I expected that by removing the first multiplication the formula would work, because I thought that Its just some kind of filtering tied to this example. But to my surprise it doesn't work. I just kept the second parenthesis formula and multiplied with just a TRUE value and it indeed works. Can someone explain why this is happening? I don't get why this is needed.